# Feynman diagram of order 3 in Yukawa theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

Is it possible to have a Feynman diagram with 3 vertices for process involving 2 initial particles and 2 final particles? For example, for the scattering of a fermion and anti-fermion in the Yukawa theory $\psi \overline{\psi} \rightarrow \psi \overline{\psi}$ where the interaction term is $\phi \psi \overline{\psi}$

Answer (score 1):

You could have for example the following $\psi \bar{\psi} \to \psi \bar{\psi}$ diagram, where there is one fermion propagator and one fermion propagator with a loop.

[image]

Comment: You mean something like this for example ? http://imgur.com/a/0vO3I What would be the physical interpretation of the loop ? The lepton emits and absorb the particle at the same space time point ?

Comment: Yes, that diagram is also possible. Feynman diagrams are terms in a perturbations series to calculate correlation functions. There is no particular physical interpretation of a single diagram (though people in popular explanations unfortunately often pretend there is).